# json4s and scala: creating custom serializer without specifying all fields

Tags: json, scala, serialization, json4s

I have two case classes and a trait in the following formats:

```
trait Parent
case class ChildClassOne(kind: String = "first_type", id: String) extends Parent
case class ChildClassTwo(kind: String = "second_type", id: String) extends Parent
```

And another case class which contains a list of `Parent`s:

```
case class ParentResponse(total: Int, results: List[Parent])
```

Basically the json response might have a list of objects which can either be of type `ChildClassOne` or `ChildClassTwo`.

Because of this (I think) I need to create a custom serializer:

```
class ParentSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Parent](format => ( {
    case JObject(List(JField("kind", JString(kind)), JField("id", JString(id)))) 
        if kind == "first_type" => ChildClassOne(kind, id) 
    case JObject(List(JField("kind", JString(kind)), JField("id", JString(id)))) 
        if kind == "second_type" => ChildClassTwo(kind, id) 
  }, {
    case _ => null
  }))
```

This works fine. Problem is that these objects might get quite big and I don't want to specify every single field in custom serializer. I'm also not modifying the properties in any way, and am using the custom serializer just to return the right type of case class based on the `kind` field.

Is there any way to avoid specifying every single field in `JObject` and just have the non-custom serializer take care of creating the right case class? eg.

```
case JObject(List(JField("kind", JString(kind)))) 
    if kind == "first_type" => read[ChildClassOne](format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using a Serializer in the end:

```
trait Parent
case class ChildClassOne(kind: String = "first_type", id: String) extends Parent
case class ChildClassTwo(kind: String = "second_type", id: String) extends Parent

case class ParentResponse(total: Int, results: List[Parent])

class ParentSerializer extends Serializer[Parent] {
    private val ParentClass = classOf[Parent]
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Parent] = {
      case (TypeInfo(ParentClass, _), json) => json match {
        case JObject(JField("kind", JString(kind)) :: _) => kind match {
          case "first_type" => json.extract[ChildClassOne]
          case "second_type" => json.extract[ChildClassTwo]
        }

        case _ => throw new MappingException("Invalid kind")
      }
    }

    def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = Map()
  }

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new ParentSerializer
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a custom serializer but you need some custom [TypeHints](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.4/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/Formats.scala#L212) to specify the mapping between your custom "kind" field and the class of the object.

```
trait Parent
case class ChildClassOne(kind: String = "first_type", id: String) extends Parent
case class ChildClassTwo(kind: String = "second_type", id: String) extends Parent

case class ParentResponse(total: Int, results: List[Parent])


object MyTypeHints extends TypeHints {
  // map class to kind and viceversa
  val classToHint: Map[Class[_], String] = Map (
    classOf[ChildClassOne] -> "first_type",
    classOf[ChildClassTwo] -> "second_type"
  )
  val hintToClass = classToHint.map(_.swap)

  override val hints: List[Class[_]] = List(classOf[ChildClassOne], classOf[ChildClassTwo])
  override def classFor(hint: String): Option[Class[_]] = hintToClass.get(hint)
  override def hintFor(clazz: Class[_]): String = classToHint(clazz)
}

implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(MyTypeHints).withTypeHintFieldName("kind")

val obj = ParentResponse(2, List(ChildClassOne(id = "one"), ChildClassTwo(id = "two")))
val serialized = Serialization.write(obj)

val deserializedFromString = Serialization.read[ParentResponse](
  """{"total":2,"results":[{"kind":"first_type","kind":"first_type","id":"one"},
    {"kind":"second_type","kind":"second_type","id":"two"}]}""")

val deserializedFromSerialized = Serialization.read[ParentResponse](serialized)

assert(obj == deserializedFromString)
assert(obj == deserializedFromSerialized)
```

If you don't need to customize the type hint field, you can use the default ones. Search for **Serializing polymorphic Lists** in the [readme](https://github.com/json4s/json4s)

Comment: One thing I can't figure out, is what if `ChildClassOne` contains another class which also has a `kind` field, but I don't want to manually define in classToHint? It seems to be ignored unless I define it there. e.g.: 

`case class ChildClassOne(kind: String = "first_type", id: String, item: Item) extends Parent` 

and item is: 

`case class(kind: String = "item_type", id: String)`

Comment: Item shouldn't have anything to do with the 'Parent' hierarchy, you don't need a type hint for it. It shouldn't be ignored, it's a completely different class

Comment: I might be wrong but I'm guessing it's because `Serialization.formats(MyTypeHints).withTypeHintFieldName("kind")` doesn't restrict it to classes extending `Parent`

Comment: you're right, there's no direct link in the formats between `Parent`  and the typehint, we could say the type hint is global...